LangSmith Evaluations on Datasets Failing
So I'm attempting to evaluate a basic dataset with 'LangSmith'. I'm just attempting the basics right now, however when I attempt to evaluate a dataset, I get this error:
ValueError: Evaluation with the <class 'langchain.evaluation.qa.eval_chain.QAEvalChain'> requires a language model to function. Failed to create the default 'gpt-4' model. Please manually provide an evaluation LLM or check your openai credentials.
And here is the code I'm using below:
run_on_dataset(
    client=client,
    dataset_name="Basic Dataset",
    llm_or_chain_factory=llm,
    evaluation=evaluation_config,
)

I've used both personal api keys from openai, and also azure openai api keys from other projects, yet I get the same error every time. I also have a check to make sure they work before hand, which is shown below:
# Load the LangSmith Client and Test Run

client = Client()

llm = ChatOpenAI(openai_api_key = '(my personal key is here...)',)
llm.predict("Hello, world!")

Any help would be massively appreciated !

Check the following link. It helped me with a similar problem when using run_on_dataset: https://docs.smith.langchain.com/old/evaluation/migration
